# nifi append key value pair to a json flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

How can i append a key/value pair to a json flowfile in Nifi. I tried `replaceText` processor with replacement strategy as `append` but the key/value pair couldn't be inserted properly inside the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `replaceText` processor with replacement strategy as `regex_replace`.

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned this on the other post, but you'll need to use a processor that understands JSON. You can use UpdateRecord for this... it would require that your schema has the extra field which you can make nullable so that the same schema can be used from the beginning, or you can have a second copy of the schema the reader in UpdateRecord would use the schema with 10 fields and the writer would use the schema with 11 fields.

Comment: I got it worked through 'replaceText' using replacement strategy as 'regex_replace'. Its simple and dont need a schema. Thats why i preferred it.
Thanks for your thoughts and timely response :-)